# PHP application with Wordpress XMLRPC - how to start?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I need to write application in PHP that supports Wordpress XML-RPC and allows to add posts from that PHP application (other website) using XML-RPC.

1. Where I can find some tutorial or examples of XML-RPC in PHP for newbies?
2. Shall I use XMLRPCPHP from http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, xmlrpc is the method of remote procedure call, where call info is xml encoded.

xmlrpc server exposes a set of remote methods with input arguments and return type.

xmlrpc supports following argument types:

- int integer value
- double double-precision floating point value
- boolean boolean value
- string string value
- dateTime date/time value
- base64 base64 encoded binary data
- array array of values
- struct structure, where each member has name and value (similar to associative arrays)

[Description of Wordpress methods exposed through xmlrpc](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)

To add a post, you need to call wp.newPost with arguments: blog id, username, password and structure, representing post content.

XMLRPCPHP is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. My XMLRPC client is working. Now I can try to write XML-RPC server.